# Invocable variable set default value

Tags: apex, invocable-method, invocablevariable

Is it possible to set default value for invocable variable? Didnt find any info.

```
@InvocableVariable(Label='Var' Required=true) 
        public String var = 'var';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. If the field is required, then the value is required, so there's no default. If you want a default value in your code, you just check if it's empty:

```
if(String.isBlank(var)) {
  var = 'var';
}
```

You'd do this in your method before using the variable. For other data types, like numbers, you can just check if it's null:

```
if(myVar == null) {
  myVar = 42;
}
```